# How to see/count the number of unique rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

For reference

```
library(vcd)
data(Arthritis)
Art = Arthritis[c("Treatment", "Sex", "Age")]
```

I want to find out the number of matching attributes in a data frame.

For example

```
Adj Name Verb
Red John Jumps
Blue John Sleeps
Red John Jumps
Red Smith Jumps
Red Smith Walks
```

In the end, I want to see:

```
Adj Name Verb Freq
Red John Jumps 2
Blue John Sleeps 1
Red Smith Jumps 1
Red Smith Walks 1
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Just do a group by count, i.e `Art %% group_by_all() %>% summarise(n = n())` or with `count` i.e. `Art %>% count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `aggregate`.

```
DAT = read.table(text="Adj Name Verb
Red John Jumps
Blue John Sleeps
Red John Jumps
Red Smith Jumps
Red Smith Walks",
header=TRUE)

aggregate(rep(1, nrow(DAT)), DAT, length)
   Adj  Name   Verb x
1  Red  John  Jumps 2
2  Red Smith  Jumps 1
3 Blue  John Sleeps 1
4  Red Smith  Walks 1
```

You could also use `sum` instead of length.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly clunkier than @G5W's, but:

```
## cross-tabulate
t1 <- with(dd,table(Adj,Name,Verb))
## convert to long format
res <- as.data.frame(t1)
## drop zeros
subset(res,Freq>0)
```